# Is my question to be kept if it receives down-votes after being answered?

Tags: discussion, too-localized

Take for example [Gravatar being used to reclaim ownership of an account, a good idea?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146550/gravatar-being-used-to-reclaim-ownership-of-an-account-a-good-idea). Nobody voted until it had an answer. Now with an answer it is harder for me to delete it.

And if I flag the question for deleting or the question gets deleted, then the person that answered it loses all the work on the answer.

So should a question which tends to get negative votes be kept to "give an example" or can I flag it for deletion (do I have this option)?

I know how to take losing points and is part of the game and my responsibility to pay when I ask stupid questions, but also I want to learn also where am I wrong. And I think here comments really help.

Comment: Don't worry about Meta reputation; the downvotes are not necessarily meant to teach you (or anyone else) a lesson. The fact that the community disagrees with the idea is a valuable piece of information. It helps define the community.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The one who answered it says: `Basically, that this isn't a terrible idea that needs shooting down, just that it is a very specialized bullet.` 

And after he/she speaks about `confirmation through an unaffiliated third-party service` not being a good-idea. But maybe people just read the final  `It looks pretty shady, honestly, is the issue.` which refers from what I get to the idea of third party service not the question in itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of a question is often mostly contained within the answers. Deleting a question just because you received some downvotes would also destroy the value contained within its answers. So you could of course flag it, but I would think (and hope) that's mostly going to be declined.

Meta rep doesn't mean a thing. Stop sweating the occasional downvotes. The rep buys you nothing.

Comment: I wouldn't flag it of course if is valuable. I just wanted to know some feedback if it is ok to have down-votes

Comment: Sure, why not. Especially here on Meta where they often indicate disagreement. I don't see why it would be a problem. The auto-ban thresholds are much more relaxed here anyway.

Comment: What is auto-ban? :O

Comment: If you have enough bad (downvoted/closed/deleted/etc.) questions or answers on Stack Overflow, you might no longer be allowed to ask a question or give an answer. But you would have to be pretty bad on SO to achieve that. And here on MSO you would really have to be beyond ridiculous to hit any ban. So don't worry about those.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: See [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)